# Move Shipping amount to the right On Cart and Checkout

Tags: css, wordpress, margin

I need to move the shipping amount from left to the right with CSS I've tried with this (I checked the source code with Chrome, then edited it and pasted it into a custom CSS in WordPress.) :

`tr.shipping span.amount {margin-left:26%;}`

but it is not working perfectly

to explain more i want it

from this:
https://pasteboard.co/K2bDdhY.png

to this:
https://pasteboard.co/K2bDo93.png

the website:

https://warnemuenderschmuckeck.de/cart/

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
tr.shipping span.amount{
 float: right;
}
```

or you can add custom class

Answer (score 1):

Or specific for the shipping

```
#shipping_method .shipping__list_label bdi {
  float: right;
}
```